# Trouble With Outputting all Elements to Console

Tags: r

I have an issue where I'm trying to use sink() to capture my console output to a text file. However, my console keeps on restricting my print statements, despite having set max.print to the maximum integer in R.

I have consulted various other stackoverflow links but to no avail. Has anyone solved this issue?

This is a sample output, despite having changed max.print.

```
options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
```

```
> print(outputFile[1])
[[1]]
+ 1681/519133 vertices, named, from 71aeda5:
   [1] p_8945206-t_25               p_24353782-t_0               p_5096967-t_0               
   [4] p_12728438-t_2               p_1914103-t_8                p_7949965-t_59              
   [7] p_5171435-t_4                p_6628106-t_7                p_2535537-t_0               
  [10] p_45026190-t_2               p_25504870-t_8               p_796238-t_1                
  [13] p_135998-t_13                p_20853906-t_1               p_17154085-t_0              
  [16] p_29505258-t_4               p_27269129-t_13              p_6793896-t_92              
  [19] p_5331193-t_1                p_11521441-t_2               p_34271996-t_2              
  [22] p_95594-t_0                  p_16395989-t_0               p_582576-t_3                
  [25] p_9368888-t_1                p_697462-t_28                p_80124-t_72                
  [28] p_7595644-t_0                p_14372110-t_4               p_2083314-t_2               
+ ... omitted several vertices
```

Additionally, I have tried indexing but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Is that an `igraph` object you're printing? Some objects will have their own print methods, possibly with their own options controlling how they're printed. It looks like there's an option `igraph_opt("auto.print.lines")` that controls `igraph` objects.

Comment: Yes, it is an igraph object/list of igraph objects. I assume I would be looking at i_graph_opt(print.full)?

Comment: https://igraph.org/r/doc/print.igraph.html --- The documentation appears to indicate that this is to print out graphs, not lists... interesting

Comment: `print(outputFile[[1]][100])` output: `+ 1/519133 vertex, named, from 71aeda5:
[1] p_3441008-t_10` and 
`typeof(outputFile[[1]][100])` output: "integer" I would assume this indicates that looking at the igraph documentation would not be very useful then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`igraph` specific options like `auto.print.lines` should still affect the printing of your graph objects, even if they're contained in a list. Using a combination of `auto.print.lines` and `max.print`, I'm able to get graphs to print out in full:

```
library(purrr)
library(igraph)

# Using purrr to create a list of multiple large graphs
gs = map(1:5, ~ random.graph.game(200, 0.1))

options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
igraph_options(auto.print.lines = Inf)

print(gs)
```